# Django model filter on list of dictionaries

Tags: django, list, dictionary, django-models, filter

I would like to filter a tabel on two values. On of which is the highest existing version of the first. First I get these two values from the first model.

```
latest_versions = Version.objects.values('post').annotate(version=Max('version'))
```

This gives me a list of dictionaries, which contains the post names with their latest version.

```
[{name: xxx, version: 1.2}{name: yyy, version: 3.4}]
```

Now I would like to use this list of dictionaries (latest_versions) as a filter on another table which has columns which are named *name* and *version*.

I thought this might work:

```
Post.objects.filter(**latest_versions)
```

But it doesn't, because it's a ValueQuerySet, a list of dictionaries. But if I iterate over the ValueQuerySet it works, but I have to make a DB call for every instance.

```
for latest_version in latestversions:
    r = Post.objects.filter(**latest_version)
    result = result + list(r)
```

What's the Pythonic way to go?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for Q objects:

```
from django.db.models import Q
...
filter_list = Q()
for item in latest_versions:
    filter_list |= Q(item)
Post.objects.filter(filter_list)
```

`filter_list` will be a list of Q objects separated by 'or'

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Comment: This would work if I new the list to be only 2 entries long. How about when the length of this list of dictionaries is unknown?

Comment: Updated the answer. Its similar to what you originally had, but instead of filtering each object which would call the database each time, you iterate through your 'latest_version' list and chain up the Q objects, separating them with 'or'.